# jsonschema multiple values for string property

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have a json schema which describes a fairly complex API querying syntax. A few of the properties are pattern matched but also need to accept other values (i.e. other explicit strings) other than just the pattern. I can't seem to find anywhere in the multitude of json schema sites any examples of this.

An example:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "$gte": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "<some-pattern>"
        }
    }
}
```

What i'd like to be able to do in the example above  is specify that `$gte` can be any of a certain set of constrained values. For example, this specific implementation requires that "$gte"'s values be constrained to one of the following:

1. A specific date format
2. A token `{token}` which gets replaced with a special value on the server-side

I've seen the `oneOf` property used in this situation but only with the `format` property so I'm assuming that this is possible, just not sure of the syntax of how to implement it, for instance it could be something like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "$gte": {
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [
                {"pattern": "<some-pattern>"},
                "{token}",
                "{another_token}"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Any clarity on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated as I'm not having much luck with the specification Draft 4 for json schema or in finding any examples.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

If you want data to be one of a fixed set of exact values, you can use `enum`:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "enum": ["stop", "go"]
}
```

So, to fit this in your example, try:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "$gte": {
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [
                {"pattern": "<some-pattern>"},
                {"enum": ["TOKEN", "ANOTHER_TOKEN"]}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what already said, for the date you can use "date" within the "oneOf"

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#dates-and-times